# Before deleting a local Git repository, check that nothing is lost

Tags: git

I want to remove a local Git repository of a project that also has a remote. But I don't want to lose anything I ever did to this repository. I have the following checklist:

- Are there any branches that are not contained in the remote repository?
- Are there any tags that are not contained in the remote repository?
- Are there any stashes?
- Are there any ignored files that may hold useful data?
- Has the index the same data as the working directory?

Is there a Git command that does all the above checks, and also those that I forgot in the above list?

Comment: "Are there any ignored files that may hold useful data?" will be impossible to answer...

Answer (score 0):

I've just moved from WSL1 to WSL2 and so (for performance) re-cloned many git repos that were in the Windows part in the Linux part instead. I wish to now remove the Windows ones after checking exactly this kind of thing. I haven't found a command that does it all - I run something like the following script which I've adapted for your checklist:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

echo "^[[31mBranches^[[0m"
git for-each-ref --format="%(refname:short) %(push:trackshort)" refs/heads | grep -v '=$'

echo -e "\n^[[31mUnpushed tags^[[0m"
git push --tags --dry-run

echo -e "\n^[[31mStash^[[0m"
git stash list

echo -e "\n^[[31mIndex and ignored files^[[0m"
git status --ignored
```

The branches section prints local branches that are either unpushed (no symbol), or behind/after/conflict with their remote (`<`, `>` or `<>`); the other sections are hopefully self-explanatory.